# Force Dagger 2 to create instance of an injected field

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a question about Dagger 2.
Is it possible to force dagger to create an instance of an injected field without calling component and its builder?

For example if we have a provider like this:

```
@provider ClassA getClassA();
```

Then in other class I can use it directly:

```
Class ClassB{
    //May be I can do something here to force dagger to create an instance of ClassA
    @inject ClassA classA;

    void doSth(){
        classA.prop1 ...
    }
}
```

Note: I don't have any access to my dagger component in ClassB!

Comment: To inject in classB, you don't need to have access to DaggerComponent in ClassB. Say you write a method in your component void inject(ClassB b);
And let's say you are building the DaggerComponent in classA, all you have to do is component.inject(b) //b = new ClassB(), and that's it. Or you can use constructor injection for classB

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the constructor with `@Inject` and you obtain ClassB from a component, then this is automatic.

```
class ClassB{
    @Inject
    ClassB() {
    }

    @Inject ClassA classA;

    void doSth(){
        classA.prop1 ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It *can* be, both works. Constructor injection is technically easier to test.